# Speed up procedure

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if this procedure can be executed faster. There are indexes on the joins and where's. Depeding on the size of `product_id_CSV` it takes approx. 2.5 sec.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `data_wijziging`(
    in TypeData varchar(50),
    in TypeCUD varchar(30), 
    in TypeId int(11), 
    in TypeToewijsId int(11)
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE product_id_CSV varchar(2000);
    DECLARE productieaantal_total int(11);
    DECLARE productieaantal int(11);
    DECLARE verdelingsid varchar(50);
    DECLARE bedrag decimal(10,2);
    DECLARE aantal int(11);

    IF(TypeData = 'materiaalverbruik') THEN

        SET verdelingsid = (SELECT kostenplaats_id FROM materiaalverbruik WHERE materiaalverbruik_id = TypeId);
        SET product_id_CSV = (SELECT CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pr.product_id),',') FROM materiaalverbruik mv 
                              INNER JOIN organogram o ON o.kostenplaats_id = mv.kostenplaats_id
                              INNER JOIN productie pr ON pr.station_id = o.station_id
                              WHERE mv.kostenplaats_id = verdelingsid AND mv.materiaalverbruik_id = TypeId);
        SET productieaantal_total = (SELECT SUM(pr.aantal) FROM materiaalverbruik mv 
                               INNER JOIN organogram o ON o.kostenplaats_id = mv.kostenplaats_id
                               INNER JOIN productie pr ON pr.station_id = o.station_id
                               WHERE mv.kostenplaats_id = verdelingsid AND mv.materiaalverbruik_id = TypeId);       

        WHILE(LOCATE(',', product_id_CSV) > 0) DO
            SET @value = LEFT(product_id_CSV, LOCATE(',',product_id_CSV) - 1);
            SET product_id_CSV = SUBSTRING(product_id_CSV, LOCATE(',', product_id_CSV) + 1);
            SET productieaantal = (SELECT SUM(pr.aantal) FROM materiaalverbruik mv 
                                   INNER JOIN organogram o ON o.kostenplaats_id = mv.kostenplaats_id
                                   INNER JOIN productie pr ON pr.station_id = o.station_id
                                   WHERE mv.kostenplaats_id = verdelingsid AND mv.materiaalverbruik_id = TypeId AND pr.product_id = @value);
            SELECT bedrag, aantal INTO bedrag, aantal FROM materiaalverbruik WHERE materiaalverbruik_id = TypeId;

            INSERT INTO materiaalverbruik_bedragen (materiaalverbruik_toewijs_id, product_id, productieaantal, materiaalaantal, bedrag)
                VALUES (TypeToewijsId, @value, productieaantal, ((aantal/productieaantal_total)*productieaantal), ((bedrag/productieaantal_total)*productieaantal));
        END WHILE;
    END IF;

END
```

Comment: Could you maybe post the table definitions and the execution plan, too?

Answer (score 0):

Consider turning `product_id_CSV` into `IN ( '...', '...', ... )` and then batching the work -- instead of looping.